# $i \neq j$ as a linear constraint where variables are binary

Tags: linear-programming, binary-variable

Let $i$ and $j$ be two binary variables.

How can I express  $i \neq  j$ as a linear constraint?

Comment: $i+j=1$ ...........

Comment: in fact,  i want to prevent  both to be 1 at the same time. how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@user3680510 gave the correct answer in a comment.  Here's a way to derive it via conjunctive normal form:
$$
i \not= j \\
(i \implies \lnot j) \land (\lnot i \implies j) \\
(\lnot i \lor \lnot j) \land (i \lor j) \\
(1 - i + 1 - j \ge 1) \land (i + j \ge 1) \\
(i + j \le 1) \land (i + j \ge 1) \\
i + j = 1
$$

---

To prevent both to be 1 at the same time:
$$
\lnot(i \land j) \\
\lnot i \lor \lnot j \\
1 - i + 1 - j \ge 1 \\
i + j \le 1
$$

Comment: in fact, i want to prevent both to be 1 at the same time. how can I do this?

Comment: I updated my answer.